# Word that means "losing through becoming aware"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that fits this quote from the Sun Also Rises (without context; I don't remember the context):
"You'll lose it, if you talk about it"

I'm having difficulty creating an example sentence, but perhaps something like this:
"Don't say this is beautiful because you will spoil it by ___"

Comment: I'm not sure there's a verb in existence that means that.

Comment: I know of a saying which says: when you try to define something (like beaty/love etc.) it can only spoil it.

Comment: Tolkien goes the whole hog with the analysis metaphor: "One who breaks a thing to find out what it is has left the path of reason.”  [Gandalf to Saruman; LOTR]

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Don't say this is beautiful because you will spoil it by [exposing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expose) it".

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> 2a : to make known : bring to light
>
> b : to exhibit for public veneration

PS You might also look at the notion of [kennings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenning). Unfortunately, I can't find the source right now, but I read somewhere that the point of kennings (that is, referring to a certain notion using a mild metaphor) was exactly not to let its features fade away by exposing them too much; if you call gold "gold" a hundred times, it will lose its shine, so a skald will always call gold "dragon's pillow" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "*jinx*" could work -

## Jinx

> : a person or thing that brings bad luck.
>
> "*One was never to wish luck to someone going hunting or fishing, as
> it was seen as a jinx.*"

---

> "Don't say this is beautiful because you will spoil it by *jinxing it*."

([From Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/jinx))

Answer (score 0):

The *single* word that comes closest to what you describe is [**define**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/define):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : to determine or identify the essential qualities or meaning of
>   // whatever defines us as human

The sentence in the question would turn into the following:

> "Don't say this is beautiful because you will spoil it by *defining* it."

---

In other words:

> If you try to put a name to something that is indescribable, you will ruin the experience of just appreciating it for what it is. Don't *think* about it, simply *feel* it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in vote for [despoil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despoil):

- to strip of belongings, possessions, or value

This would mean rewording your sentence a bit, perhaps like:

> "Don't say this is beautiful because you will despoil it."